# How to execute Stored Procedures with Symfony2, Doctrine2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, stored-procedures, doctrine-orm

I am using the following code:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
...
...
...
...
$em    = $this->get( 'doctrine.orm.entity_manager' );
$rsm   = new ResultSetMapping();
$query = $em->createNativeQuery( 'CALL procedureName(:param1, :param2)', $rsm )
            ->setParameters( array(
                'param1' => 'foo',
                'param2' => 'bar'
            ) );
$result = $query->getResult();
//$result = $query->execute(); // Also tried

$em->flush();
die(var_dump($result));
```

I am not getting any thing in the $result parameter. Can anyone please tell me how to get the result from a stored procedure in Symfony 2.0.15 ?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't added any resultset mapping info. See [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#examples) for sample.

Comment: Hi m2mdas, I am pretty new to Doctrine can you please explain what do I need to add there?

The problem that I have is like I have 3 table:
users(id,username,groupType[discriminator column]); user_group1(id,firstName,lastName); user_group2(id,displayName);

Now I want to query based on user id and ( (firstName OR lastName) OR displayName )

I am not able to make a DQL for that. So, I decided to make an Stored Procedure where I had the problem explained above.

Comment: I haven't worked with class table inheritance so I can give any correct answer on that. Search for `setDiscriminatorColumn` in the doc. However if you want to get array result instead of entity object you can do it by [addScalarResult](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#scalar-results). For example `$rsm->addScalarResult('username', 'username');`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use plain `PDO`. In the following example I call a stored procedure and get value of the `OUT` parameter.

Procedure with `IN` and `OUT` parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `CLONE_MEMBER_PRODUCT` (IN ID INT, OUT NEW_ID INT)
BEGIN
    /* ... */
END;
```

`getWrappedConnection()` returns instance of `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection` which is just a wrapper for `PDO`

```
/* @var $connection \PDO */
$connection = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->getConnection()
    ->getWrappedConnection();

$stmt = $connection->prepare('CALL CLONE_MEMBER_PRODUCT(?, @NEW_ID)');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $connection->query("SELECT @NEW_ID");
$id = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```