# Execute Oracle stored procedures with Symfony & doctrine

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, stored-procedures, doctrine

I am trying to execute an stored procedures inside an Oracle database :

```
x_pkg.get_xID
```

It require one input & will output a single string

I already tried several different options that I found in internet :

```
$val = 'DATABASE';
$result = new ResultSetMapping ();

$query  = $entityManager -> createNativeQuery ("BEGIN x_pkg.get_xID(${val}, :cursor); END;", $result);
```

In this case I get error : ORA-01008: not all variables bound (500 Internal Server Error)

```
$query = $entityManager -> createNativeQuery ("CALL x_pkg.get_xID(:data)", $result);
$query -> setParameters (['data' => $val]);
```

In this case I get error : ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_XID' (500 Internal Server Error)

```
$query = $entityManager -> createNativeQuery ("CALL x_pkg.get_xID(${val})", $result);
```

In this case I get error : ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name (500 Internal Server Error)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512868/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-with-symfony2-doctrine2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you explain why you get these errors and then it might help you to find the solution to solve the problem,

And just keep it in mind, the Oracle database is a bit tricky and different than other community used database such as MySQL, it has it's own power and strict rules,

**I will explain the first case at the end.*

So, in your second case, you get that error because Oracle expect the *OUT* variable to be a part of your *Call* which is not the case in your code and because it is inside the procedure

In your third case, using *${val}* is not valid even if it's valid for PHP itself, the Oracle database see it in other way, so this is not an option for you,

Now about the first case, you should make sure that your procedure is returning a *cursor* and not a variable, I think you should check it in your Oracle database and also in your next line of code where you execute your query (it's not posted here so I can't be sure about it), this is a tricky part of Oracle database, you should make sure what your procedure is returning to avoid the error,

And good luck :)

Comment: You are right, the problem was with the cursor, the procedure doesn't return a cursor but the generated id